# JQuery and PHP not print &amp;

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Can someone advise me on how to handle this situation?

I use PHP and JQuery together to create a new url with parameters. However, it's not putting in the ampersand in the url, but rather "#38;". Browsers won't read my second parameter then. I've also tried using "& #38;" (broken to display on SO) which creates echoes it literally, simple "&" also resulting in the html code, "\$" > hex, "&&" > htmlhtml...

How do I get the script to create the &?

I work on the wordpress platform in text mode.

This is what I get when using "&naam":
[image: HTML write]

**Coding:**

```
echo "<script>  
            $(function() {
                $('.checked').click(function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var dialog = $('<strong>Wat is jou RSVP keuse?</strong>').dialog({
                            buttons: {
                                \"Ja\": function() {
                                            window.location.href = \"http://hannelliemarcel.co.za/rsvp-ja?email=" . $Email . "&naam=" . $Naam . "\";
                                        },
                                \"Nee\":  function() {
                                            window.location.href = \"http://hannelliemarcel.co.za/rsvp-nee?email=" . $Email . "&naam=" . $Naam . "\";
                                        },
                                \"Kanselleer\":  function() {
                                    dialog.dialog('close');
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
        </script>";
```

Comment: http://hannelliemarcel.co.za/rsvp-ja?email=xyz@xyz.com&naam=xyz  -- this is your expected result ?

Comment: works fine for me if you just use window.location.href = \"http://hannelliemarcel.co.za/rsvp-ja?email=" . $Email . "&naam=" . $Naam . "\"; 1 ampersand

Comment: Just tried that, but it still writes to $38;. Updated the original question with a screenshot.

Comment: Why do you have `"&&naam="`? Try `"&naam="` or `"&amp;naam="`. Make use your script is encoded with UTF-8

Comment: Instead of having huge echo tags, why not end your PHP tag, output the `<script>` tag, and start another PHP tag after it? That way you don't have to escape all your quotes.

Comment: I've checked everything: The site uses charset UTF-8, the script is encoded to UTF-8 still getting & #38; Even added the function to write the character by means of encodeURI('&') which results in # 038;

Comment: It works now when I use the UTF-8 code for the ampersand. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by means of using the encodeURI (); function within Javascript to use parametrized urls.

Instead of using the HTML code for the ampersand, which is & #38;, I used the UTF-8 format of ampersand, which is \u0026. This is a much safer way of encoding the character.

This is then how it should look like:

```
<script>
  function createAmp(){
    var symb = encodeURI('\u0026');
    document.getElementById('contentArea').innerHTML = "http://example.com/foo?id=123" + symb + "name=john";
  }
</script>
```

Thanks to everyone's suggestions in the comments, especially @milz.